# Fitness exercises for anybody near the age of 50

Tags: workout-routines, bodyweight-exercises, home-exercise

For a person who is near the age of 50 what exercises do you recommend to do at home without any heavy gym equipment to maintain a proper shape and remain fit in old age.

I cannot buy any heavy equipment which takes up a lot of space like treadmills, etc.

I'm looking for something similar to exercises involving dumbbells or maybe resistance bands or anything else. Or even yoga, etc...

Comment: It might help if you did some research beforehand. There are thousands of beginner workouts online, with dumbells or without. Have you looked at a couple? What's keeping you from trying them out? If you only want an opinion or "that's what I do", the stack exchange network might not be ideal for that. Ask your friends and family, they might offer you more consistent help

Comment: @Raditz_35 That is the problem my friend, there are just so many of them. I find that stackexchange is a website where a lot of professionals with lot of experience are there and my experience is so far that it is very trustable source. I do not want to end up just beging something random and and keep doing it for a long time and suffer and detoriate my health because health once gone is gone at this stage and this was looking for some advice from stackexchange.

Comment: I see and I think that's a legitimate thought. However, the more work you put into your question, focusing it, being specific about your needs, resources and goals, learning the easily googled basics (don't have those pros explain to you 200 different things you can do beforehand, that's a waste of time), the more effort you put into this, the more you can profit. I am convinced that the better the question, the more helpful the answer should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fitness strategy should have 3 equally important parts:

- strength
- mobility
- cardio

For mobility you only need a yoga mat as equipment and maybe some elastic bands. For cardio you need a pair of good jogging shoes or a bike.

When it comes to strength you do need some heavy equipment. However this do not need to take up a lot of space.

The exercises in the Starting Strength program are the most "bang for buck" strength exercises.
You can use a heavy dumbell to do goblet squats instead of backsquats.
Also you can do push-ups (with a weight plate) on your back instead of benchpress.
The biggest problem will be the deadlift which also happens to be the single most important strength exercise. For this you will need a barbell and a lot of weights.
I would think you need this:

- 2 x adjustable dumbells with up to 40 kg on one dumbell
- barbell + minimum your bodyweight in weight plates

Maybe its a good idea to get 50 mm (olympic) dumbells so that you can use the same plates for both the dumbells and the barbell.
A shorter 10 kg barbell will probably suffice unless you are very strong.

Elastic bands are nice for mobility and physiotherapist style rehab/prehab but useless for strength alone.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It was really helpful :-)